# How to tokenize a String into its ngrams using Lucene in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, lucene, tokenize

I have the following method in Scala which tokenize a string and use the EnglishAnayzer to stem the terms and get rid of the stop words. However I want to split the string into ngrams using lucece too. Could someone help me with the code?

```
 def tokenize(content: String): Seq[String] = {

val LuceneVersion = Version.LUCENE_46
val tReader = new StringReader(content)
val analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer(LuceneVersion)
val tStream = analyzer.tokenStream("contents",tReader)
val term = tStream.addAttribute(classOf[CharTermAttribute])
tStream.reset()

val result = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
while(tStream.incrementToken()){
  result += term.toString()
}   
result
}
```

Should I have the ngram first and the use the EnglishAnalyzer to stem the extracted terms and get rid of the stop words?

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the order should be in your case, first you have to get the tokenStream from the original string then tokenize the input tokenStream of n-gram accroding to your demand. The method in NGramTokenFilter may further proves that.

```
 // org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.NGramTokenFilter
 public final class NGramTokenFilter extends TokenFilter { 
    // line 51
    public NGramTokenFilter(TokenStream input, int minGram, int maxGram) {
    ...
 }
```

Following is how I try to get it done based on the description you offer.

```
  import java.io.{ Reader, StringReader }
  import org.apache.lucene.util.Version.LUCENE_34
  import org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.NGramTokenFilter
  import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute
  import org.apache.lucene.analysis.{ TokenStream, Analyzer }
  import org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer

  object NgramTest extends App {
     class NGramAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
        def tokenStream(fieldName: String, reader: Reader): TokenStream = {
        val originalStream = (new EnglishAnalyzer(LUCENE_34)).reusableTokenStream(fieldName, reader)

        // n-gram with size 2 ~ 3
        new NGramTokenFilter(originalStream, 2, 3)
       }
     }

    def simpleTokenStreamList(tokenStream: TokenStream) = {
       val term = tokenStream.addAttribute(classOf[CharTermAttribute])
       Stream.continually(
          (tokenStream.incrementToken, term.toString)
       ).takeWhile(_._1).map {
          t => t._2
       }.toList
     }

    val nGramAnalyzer = new NGramAnalyzer
    val ngramStream = nGramAnalyzer.tokenStream("sample", new StringReader("A letter from mother"))
    val result = simpleTokenStreamList(ngramStream)

    // List(le, et, tt, te, er, let, ett, tte, ter, fr, ro, om, fro, rom, mo, ot, th, he, er, mot, oth, the, her)
   println(result)
 }
```

Besides, in **Lucene In Action 2nd, Chapter 8.2.2 Ngram filters** has a detailed explanation of Ngram filters. I suggest you have a read maybe you will find your answer.

Anyway, hope it helps.